# How can one convert an environment variable to a string in groovy

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

In a jenkins file pipeline I have:

```
def task = readJSON(file: 'ecs/task-definition.json')
echo "Read Task Definition: $task"
task.containerDefinitions[0].image="${AWS_VERSION_IMAGE}"
echo "New Task Definition With Image Is: $task"
```

In the output value of the second echo statement i get:

```
New Task Definition With Image Is: [name:proxy, image:[bytes:[48, 48, 55, 49, 50, 54, 53, 56, 51, 55, 53, 55, 46, 100, 107, 114, 46]]
```

where `AWS_VERSION_IMAGE` is an environment variable defined as `AWS_VERSION_IMAGE = "${AWS_DOCKER_REGISTRY}:${VERSION_TAG}"` in an `environment` block.

Comment: Does `System.getenv('AWS_VERSION_IMAGE')` get you what you're looking for?

Comment: What does a simple “echo AWS_VERSION_INFO“ print? And what about echo “${env.AVS_VERSION_INFO}”?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the replies, I ended up fixing the issue by using `String` instead of `def` like this:

```
String image = "${AWS_VERSION_IMAGE}"
task.containerDefinitions[0].image=image
```

Now it works.